# jQuery UI .effect not working

Tags: jquery-ui

For some reason my site isn't recognizing jQuery UI's functions. Wappalyzer says that the site is accessing UI, but Firebug is saying that the easing effects aren't defined.

My site is www.backwards.ca

I'm obviously just beginning it, but I'm curious as to why things aren't happening with jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved... forgot the "https:" in the script tag